# Fusion Charts Stop Propagation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, fusioncharts

I am using [Fusion Charts](http://fusioncharts.com) for some of my charting work. Now what I want is that when someone clicks the background of my chart, he gets an advanced menu, and when someone clicks on the plotted data, he gets drill down charts. The documentation shows `evt.stopPropagation()` function is there, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my code :

```
    FusionCharts.ready(function(){
        var myChart=new FusionCharts({
            type: 'mscolumn3d',
            renderAt: 'chart-container',
            width: '400',
            height: '300',
            dataFormat: 'json',
            dataSource: {
                "chart": {
                    "caption": "Weekly Sales Summery",
                    "subCaption": "",
                    "xAxisName": "Week",
                    "yAxisName": "Amount",
                    "numberPrefix": "$",               
                    "theme": "fint"
                },

                "categories": [{
                    "category": [{
                        "label": "Sales"
                    }]
                }],
                "dataset": [{
                    "seriesname": "Week1",
                        "data": [{
                        "value": "14400"
                    }]
                }]
            }
        });
        myChart.addEventListener("dataplotclick",function(e,d){
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        myChart.addEventListener("chartClick",function(e,d){
            console.log(e);
        });
        myChart.render();
});
```

The event is triggered regard less of where user has clicked. And when the event is logged, stopPropagation() is not enabled in the logging. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, but I don't see any `stopPropagation()` calls in your code. In case you don't know, `preventDefault()` only prevents the default action from occurring. It does not stop event bubbling.

Comment: Oops, sorry I was removing preventDefault when I pasted here, I mistakenly have removed stopPropagation. WIll edit.